# Can`t save .pdf document which sended from .Net api

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2

I got an Api which return File, i write response into this.getPDFBuffer, here you can see it.
Main problem is that if I use my function it downloads an empty file, but if i use Postman to perform an request it saves correctly

//this.getPDFBuffer contains response.data:

```
      var file = new Blob([this.getPDFBuffer], {type: 'application/pdf'});
      var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
      var link = document.createElement('a');
      link.setAttribute('href', url);
      link.setAttribute('download','download');
      link.click();
```

I expect download a file

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer but:

On line 4 and line 5, I suggest using a `link.href = url;` instead of `setAttribute()`. For line 5, it is `link.download = "download";`. This could fix the problem, but this is not meant to be a fix, just a tip.

You also have to `document.body.appendChild(link)` probably after line 5 so it gets displayed in the HTML.

Also, on line 5, you might have to set different parameters(see https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_a_download.asp).

Changed code:

```
var file      = new Blob([this.getPDFBuffer], {type: 'application/pdf'});
var url       = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
var link      = document.createElement('a');
link.href     = url;
link.download = "download"; // Maybe 'link.download;'

document.body.appendChild(link)
link.click();
```

Comment: thanks, but i forgot to say that document is saving, but he is empty. I try make request from Postman, then save, and it saves successfully.

Comment: Ok. I have no experience with .NET so I am the person not to ask... :)

Comment: This is not .Net problem i think

Comment: Really? I would do a Google search or look at how you're getting the PDF

Comment: Maybe it's the download element? On W3Schools, the download attribute has nothing, not even a = sign

Comment: If i open file from link it also empty, that`s not download problem

Comment: Maybe the file is empty

Comment: Weird. You're using .NET right? Maybe check the docs. Are you downloading from local server, local file, or an external server? If it's external, it could be that they don't allow file downloads?

Comment: i am using Vue.js, api isn`t mine, i just need to receive an file and download it

Comment: Also have no experience with Vue.js

Comment: there is no need in Vuejs, this function is pure js

Comment: So the `new Blob` is not Vuejs? You could have the wrong types of parameters.

Comment: You might want to use a pure url instead of making a new Blob and getting the url from that